# Xamarin Forms Show Picker Inside Shell Page

Tags: c#, shell, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a shell app where it contains flyout items and menu items. I want a picker to show when a menu item is clicked. But it appears that bindable objects like picker, frame, entry... cannot be added in a page that inherits **Shell** class. So is there a way to show a picker or I have to create a content page and place the picker inside it?

Xaml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bufib.Tools"
            xmlns:static="clr-namespace:Bufib.Tools"
            xmlns:flyout="clr-namespace:Bufib.Views.FlyoutPages"
            xmlns:others="clr-namespace:Bufib.Views.Others"
            x:Class="Bufib.MainPage"
            BackgroundImageSource="{local:ImageResource Bufib.Logos.bg.jpg}">
    
    <!-- styling -->
    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static static:Constants.PRIMARY_COLOR}}" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>
    <!-- end styling-->
        
    <!-- NAVIGATION HEADER AND PAGES-->
    <Shell.FlyoutHeader>
      ...
    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>
    ...
    <!-- END NAVIGATION -->
    
    <!---Menu Items -->
    <MenuItem x:Name="editHistoryLbl" Clicked="editHistoryLbl_Clicked" IconImageSource="{local:ImageResource Bufib.Logos.settings.png}"/>
     ...
    <!--- END Menu Items -->
</Shell>
```

CS to show picker:

```
private void editHistoryLbl_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<int> numbersLst = new List<int>(){ -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            Picker picker = new Picker();
            picker.ItemsSource = numbersLst;
            picker.IsVisible = true;
            this.Items.Add(picker);
        }
```

Comment: From your description, you want to add Picker control in [Xamarin.Forms Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/introduction)? there are three main hierarchical objects: FlyoutItem or TabBar, Tab, ShellContent, you can not add picker control in Shell class directly.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT yeah I thought so I had to place it inside a content page.

Comment: yes, you can do it.